# All possible normal subgroups of a direct product.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

Let $A$ and $B$ be two groups of co-prime orders. Let $G=A \times B$. Then I want to find all possible normal subgroups of $G$.

It can be shown that it $A'$ and $B'$ are normal subgroups of $A$ and $B$, respectively, then $A'\times B'$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Is there any other subgroup of $G$ that is not of the form of direct product of normal subgroups?

I know that it the orders of $A$ and $B$ are not co-prime then there exist normal subgroups that are not direct product.

Comment: In general, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485512/subgroups-of-a-direct-product?rq=1). There is the Lemma by Goursat.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Is this a good duplicate?  This post concerns groups of relatively prime order...the examples presented in the other do not satisfy that condition.

Comment: @lulu  I see. I have not seen the last sentence first. So I have reopened the question (although I think it is known here). So for non-coprime orders there are counterexamples given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639125/normal-subgroups-of-direct-product?noredirect=1&lq=1).